# Using Om Tat Sat mantra in daily life

Tags: bhagavad-gita, mantras

This mantra was explained in Bhagavad-Gita, it's used while performing yagna, dana or tapa.
How to use this mantra in daily life ?
For eg. Just before starting meal
Can this mantra be used ? Or bathing ? Or starting new activities ?
Are the above  activities considered holy ?
Bhagavad-Gita mentions using the mantra while performing holy activities.

Comment: First u need to understand what it means. Om Tat Sat- Om that is truth. So, it is not the kind of Mantra that people use before activities like say eating or bathing. For those purposes different Mantras are usually used. However, those who are solely devoted to Brahman or the absolute (meaning who have reached that stage by their practices), this becomes the only Mantra of their lives.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74485/discussion-on-question-by-christopher-using-om-tat-sat-mantra-in-daily-life).

Comment: many people chant Gita 4.24 before meals.

Comment: Food offered to god is a sacrifice, so before offering can Om Tat Sat be used.

Comment: Food offered to god is a sacrifice -- That is true but for that purpose other Mantras are used not this one. @Christopher

Comment: @Rickross in Bhagavad-Gita Shree Krishna clearly said, Om Tat Sat is used before performing yagna, Dana or tapa.

Comment: @Christopher As i said before before eating one needs to chant other mantras..similarly before bathing too there are separate mantras which are chanted..